# strong parameters for dynamic keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

Below is my params, how to write strong parameters for this ?

```
"foo" => {"54" => {"name" => "test", "age" => "10"}, "93" => {"name" => "test3", "age" => "20"}}
```

Is there anyway to write other than below one ?

```
def foo_params
  params.permit(foo: [:name,:age])
end
```

Comment: You can use `params.permit!`. It is only one way because your data is dynamic.

Comment: Why do you need these numbers to be sent? I mean, what a 54 key turns into ? is it an ID ?

Comment: yes it's ID, here I gave sample data. But in project i can't change params. thats'y i am asking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
params.permit(foo: [:name, :age]).require(:foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
params.permit(:foo => {"54" => [:name, :age], "93" => [:name, :age]})
```

Comment: He meant dynamic data, so those numbers would change in each request

Comment: lcguida you are correct. 54,93 are dynamic keys,its not predictable

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had params

```
"products"=>{"0"=>{"title"=>"item1", "price"=>"123123"}, "1"=>{"title"=>"item2", "price"=>"123123"}}
```

what I tried

```
params.require(:products).permit =>

Unpermitted parameters: :0, :1
<ActionController::Parameters {} permitted: true>
```

Solution

```
params.require(:products).permit! =>

<ActionController::Parameters {"0"=><ActionController::Parameters {"title"=>"item1", "price"=>"123123"} permitted: true>, "1"=><ActionController::Parameters {"title"=>"item2", "price"=>"123123"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```